# TypeScript files don't compile to JavaScript files in .NET core 2.0 test project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution in VS2017 which DOES compile the TS files in the web project (.net core 2.0) but not in the test project (.net core 2.0).

Is that by design?

I can't find any setting that says in the webproject 'autocompile the TS files' (does VS2017 compile TS files out-of-the-box?), so I can't check whether that setting is on or off on the testproject.

EDIT
I did find that the web project has a tab 'typescript build' in the properties of the project, and the test project has not.
So I guess this means that the testproject is not intended for typescript building; however, can it made to be like it?

I don't want to change my testproject to webproject I guess, just to make it compile TypeScript files.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#msbuild

Comment: I'm honestly unsure about your particular question... Thought I would comment saying that I have been using Task Runner Explorer to trigger webpack compiling of my typescript files and that works a treat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation is directed by what `target` files are imported into your project. If you open your web project file (open the `.csproj` as xml) you will see the sdk used is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, while for a unit test project the sdk is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. These SDKs point to folders in `c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\` (or equivalent depending on your setup) that will be used for default imports into your project.

If we dig around a bit into what is included for `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` that is related to Typescript, we find the following:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets') AND '$(EnableTypeScriptNuGetTarget)' != 'true'" />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.DotNetCore.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.DotNetCore.targets') AND '$(EnableTypeScriptNuGetTarget)' != 'true'" />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```

If we add these lines inside the `Project` tag in our unit test project file (`.csproj`) we will include the necessary build steps for Typescript. You will also get the Typescript property page in your project.

**Note** I have not tested this extensively but it appears to work, if you have any problems, let me know.